# Pandas not normalizing data properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, candlestick-chart

I am trying to normalize a dataframe of candlestick values. Here is the original graph:

[not normalized data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3MFU.png)

And here is the normalised graph:

[normalized graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpKtM.png)

As you can see the graph has a similar shape however most of the wicks and bodies are completely unproportionate and some wicks even go inside of the body. Heres the code maybe im missing something.

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
import pandas as pd
from creds import user, password
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objs as go

if not mt5.initialize(login=user, password=password, server="FTMO-Demo"):
    print("initialize() failed, error code =", mt5.last_error())
    quit()

symbols = mt5.symbols_get()
convertedCandles = pd.DataFrame(columns=["candleType", "wicksUp", "wicksDown", "bodySize", "time"])

rates = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos("GBPJPY", mt5.TIMEFRAME_M15, 0, 15000)
ticker = pd.DataFrame(rates)

time = pd.DataFrame()

ticker['time'] = pd.to_datetime(ticker['time'], unit='s')
time['time'] = ticker['time']
ticker['time'] = time['time']
ticker = ticker.set_index('time')
ticker = ticker.tail(100)
df_max = ticker["high"].max()
df_min = ticker["low"].min()

# Normalize data
ticker=(ticker-ticker.min())/(ticker.max()-ticker.min())

qf = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=ticker.index,
                open=ticker['open'],
                high=ticker['high'],
                low=ticker['low'],
                close=ticker['close'])])

plotly.offline.plot(qf, filename='../gauge-meter-chart.html')
```

My aim is to have the same candlestick pattern however I would like the x axis to be from 0 to 1.

As seen here:
[desired graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7zOd.png)

Dataframe not normalized:

```
                        open      high       low     close
time                                                       
2022-10-21 10:00:00  0.725194  0.659922  0.750700  0.723379
2022-10-21 10:15:00  0.720716  0.751341  0.774720  0.832202
2022-10-21 10:30:00  0.830544  0.747684  0.848647  0.798268
2022-10-21 10:45:00  0.796842  0.707216  0.776586  0.722443
2022-10-21 11:00:00  0.719774  0.628230  0.737174  0.688977
2022-10-21 11:15:00  0.686778  0.635056  0.734608  0.695764
2022-10-21 11:30:00  0.692435  0.615310  0.711054  0.684999
2022-10-21 11:45:00  0.682536  0.599464  0.696595  0.668149
2022-10-21 12:00:00  0.665802  0.640907  0.710354  0.707231
2022-10-21 12:15:00  0.704926  0.610678  0.721315  0.687807
2022-10-21 12:30:00  0.685600  0.595076  0.662313  0.619237
2022-10-21 12:45:00  0.615366  0.564359  0.674674  0.643576
2022-10-21 13:00:00  0.640584  0.584837  0.683769  0.644980
2022-10-21 13:15:00  0.642706  0.544369  0.659981  0.634449
2022-10-21 13:30:00  0.631393  0.569478  0.681903  0.665106
2022-10-21 13:45:00  0.662032  0.682106  0.719916  0.744208
2022-10-21 14:00:00  0.742399  0.715992  0.796175  0.793822
2022-10-21 14:15:00  0.791657  0.760848  0.849347  0.823777
2022-10-21 14:30:00  0.821353  0.729400  0.812034  0.773929
2022-10-21 14:45:00  0.771624  0.682838  0.785448  0.747016
2022-10-21 15:00:00  0.745699  0.685032  0.771688  0.722209
2022-10-21 15:15:00  0.720481  0.635544  0.744869  0.695062
2022-10-21 15:30:00  0.692670  0.635544  0.714319  0.714018
2022-10-21 15:45:00  0.711289  0.737933  0.768190  0.807161
2022-10-21 16:00:00  0.803912  0.822038  0.860774  0.843904
2022-10-21 16:15:00  0.842329  0.819600  0.871269  0.880412
2022-10-21 16:30:00  0.878859  0.846904  0.891791  0.870583
2022-10-21 16:45:00  0.869903  0.879327  0.920476  0.963960
2022-10-21 17:00:00  0.963941  0.954900  0.987407  0.989937
2022-10-21 17:15:00  0.989159  0.914188  0.954757  0.919729
2022-10-21 17:30:00  0.918218  0.845929  0.733675  0.735081
2022-10-21 17:45:00  0.728494  0.674549  0.463853  0.573134
2022-10-21 18:00:00  0.569408  0.470502  0.204058  0.170606
2022-10-21 18:15:00  0.164271  0.219405  0.077659  0.232155
2022-10-21 18:30:00  0.225784  0.189907  0.125466  0.161011
2022-10-21 18:45:00  0.152015  0.048513  0.000000  0.000000
2022-10-21 19:00:00  0.000000  0.117747  0.045243  0.212965
2022-10-21 19:15:00  0.210229  0.140907  0.060168  0.070910
2022-10-21 19:30:00  0.063634  0.000000  0.042444  0.095951
2022-10-21 19:45:00  0.088381  0.055826  0.106810  0.154926
2022-10-21 20:00:00  0.148008  0.102389  0.205924  0.202668
2022-10-21 20:15:00  0.196795  0.203559  0.261894  0.314767
2022-10-21 20:30:00  0.309215  0.318625  0.361007  0.427802
2022-10-21 20:45:00  0.424700  0.368357  0.484608  0.445823
2022-10-21 21:00:00  0.440726  0.337396  0.363806  0.404166
2022-10-21 21:15:00  0.399481  0.328376  0.415345  0.436462
2022-10-21 21:30:00  0.432713  0.342760  0.391325  0.338170
2022-10-21 21:45:00  0.334433  0.276207  0.272155  0.249239
2022-10-21 22:00:00  0.243224  0.145295  0.182836  0.192605
2022-10-21 22:15:00  0.186189  0.148708  0.242537  0.248303
2022-10-21 22:30:00  0.242281  0.220868  0.304804  0.321086
2022-10-21 22:45:00  0.315107  0.294003  0.373368  0.402059
2022-10-21 23:00:00  0.397360  0.329352  0.335821  0.354084
2022-10-21 23:15:00  0.349045  0.295709  0.371968  0.399251
2022-10-21 23:30:00  0.393589  0.305705  0.425606  0.389422
2022-10-21 23:45:00  0.384634  0.312774  0.417211  0.366721
2022-10-24 00:00:00  0.684421  0.609703  0.702659  0.706763
2022-10-24 00:15:00  0.703983  0.637981  0.740205  0.722677
2022-10-24 00:30:00  0.718360  0.688445  0.774953  0.783758
2022-10-24 00:45:00  0.781758  0.738664  0.840019  0.817692
2022-10-24 01:00:00  0.816168  1.000000  0.848647  0.902879
2022-10-24 01:15:00  0.901485  0.908581  0.892957  0.869647
2022-10-24 01:30:00  0.870846  0.842028  0.903685  0.893049
2022-10-24 01:45:00  0.891822  0.890541  0.887593  0.946876
2022-10-24 02:00:00  0.946264  0.865431  0.924207  0.904985
2022-10-24 02:15:00  0.904784  0.848854  0.945896  0.935408
2022-10-24 02:30:00  0.933773  0.899074  0.125000  0.168734
2022-10-24 02:45:00  0.109357  0.559483  0.158116  0.514159
2022-10-24 03:00:00  0.518265  0.639688  0.548741  0.693892
2022-10-24 03:15:00  0.691492  0.654559  0.709188  0.743038
2022-10-24 03:30:00  0.740749  0.671624  0.687500  0.742570
2022-10-24 03:45:00  0.739807  0.761824  0.776819  0.779312
2022-10-24 04:00:00  0.778694  0.750609  0.822062  0.836181
2022-10-24 04:15:00  0.834551  0.753047  0.774021  0.797800
2022-10-24 04:30:00  0.794721  0.771819  0.853545  0.824713
2022-10-24 04:45:00  0.823003  0.755729  0.840252  0.811842
2022-10-24 05:00:00  0.810511  0.730132  0.793377  0.757781
2022-10-24 05:15:00  0.755362  0.723549  0.807369  0.817692
2022-10-24 05:30:00  0.814989  0.731107  0.853778  0.797800
2022-10-24 05:45:00  0.795899  0.719405  0.826959  0.773461
2022-10-24 06:00:00  0.772802  0.687470  0.811800  0.768547
2022-10-24 06:15:00  0.766203  0.680400  0.796175  0.756377
2022-10-24 06:30:00  0.754183  0.675280  0.804104  0.760356
2022-10-24 06:45:00  0.759133  0.665773  0.795476  0.743974
2022-10-24 07:00:00  0.742164  0.683813  0.800373  0.751463
2022-10-24 07:15:00  0.749234  0.729644  0.803638  0.819331
2022-10-24 07:30:00  0.817582  0.788152  0.870336  0.868945
2022-10-24 07:45:00  0.867311  0.817894  0.925373  0.895858
2022-10-24 08:00:00  0.892058  0.804486  0.902752  0.876901
2022-10-24 08:15:00  0.876267  0.802779  0.900886  0.868476
2022-10-24 08:30:00  0.867547  0.807411  0.919076  0.891879
2022-10-24 08:45:00  0.891115  0.874939  0.940532  0.925813
2022-10-24 09:00:00  0.925289  0.935885  0.975047  1.000000
2022-10-24 09:15:00  1.000000  0.917845  1.000000  0.945940
2022-10-24 09:30:00  0.944615  0.872257  0.942397  0.954599
2022-10-24 09:45:00  0.952864  0.905900  0.992537  0.973789
2022-10-24 10:00:00  0.972425  0.922964  0.993937  0.957875
2022-10-24 10:15:00  0.956399  0.903706  0.988106  0.948514
2022-10-24 10:30:00  0.947679  0.879815  0.939832  0.907559
2022-10-24 10:45:00  0.905491  0.849829  0.945196  0.909431

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: good to see actual data - but fyi, and to eliminate you own code, try using sklearn [MinMaxScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html)

Comment: Ive tried MinMaxScaler gives the same result basically

Comment: To modify the y-axis scale, set the scale value and scale string to the expected scale. `fig.update_yaxes(tickvals=[0,1], ticktext=[0,1])` Also, regarding normalization, is it necessary to calculate with the maximum and minimum value of each price?

Comment: Im not sure what type of normalization to use, the main thing is that the candles have the same shape but all values are between 1 and 0. Also just changing the y axis to 0 to 1 isnt really my main aim. The aim is to normalize the data, im just using the graph to see wether the shape stays the same.